# Java generics - Convert to generics type

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying out java to create a queue using arrays. It works for a String type and wanted to convert the same code to use generics, to practice generic coding. I am struct where I use streams to print this generic type. Any help?

```
main method:
QueueArrays queue = new QueueArrays<String>();
queue.enqueue("Jack");
```

```
class QueueArrays<T>{
int size;
ArrayList<T> queue;
public QueueArrays(){
    this.queue = new ArrayList<>(10);
    size=0;
}
public QueueArrays enqueue(T value){
    this.queue.add(value);
    size++;
    return this;
}
   
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void printQueue(){
 System.out.println(this.queue.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")));   
}
```

How to convert printQueue for generics?

Comment: Note: You need `QueueArrays<String> queue = new QueueArrays<>();`, otherwise `queue` is a raw type (i.e., not parameterized).

Comment: As for `printQueue()`, you need to convert `T` to a `String`. The only thing you know about `T` is that it is "at least" an `Object`. So, the most straightforward option is to `map` the objects with `Object::toString`.

Comment: By the way, your current implementation is nearly identical to `System.out.println(queue)`. The only difference being you use `","` instead of `", "` as the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collectors.joining()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) requires stream elements, which are [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

To cite:

> Returns:
> A Collector which concatenates CharSequence elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order

So you must either:

1. Declare bound of the generic type, to be `CharSequence`

```
class QueueArrays<T extends CharSequence> {
}
```

2. Or map the elements of the stream to a type implementing `CharSequence`, mapping to `String` being the easiest

```
this.queue.stream()
     .map(Object::toString)
     .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
```

Additional note, no need to return raw type here:

```
public QueueArrays enqueue(T value){
    //
}
```

You should return `QueueArrays<T>` instead.